# wso2am reverse proxy with different url context

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I'm using wso2am version 3.2.0 and trying to configure reverse proxy using nginx following the below mentioned documentation.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/configuring-the-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/

I want to access devportal and publisher with different context as below
devportal: https://{domain-name}/wso2am/devportal
publisher: https://{domain-name}/wso2am/publisher

How to achieve this?
I have changed the location block like the one below. But it is not working.

```
    location /wso2am/ {
                                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                                    proxy_read_timeout 5m;
                                    proxy_send_timeout 5m;
                                    proxy_pass https://<IP>:9443/;
}
```

Comment: You can use nginx or any reverse proxy to handle this requirement

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have just updated the question with some more details. Could you please check it.